# What is the easiest way to get the partition uuid of a partition in UEFI?

Tags: uuid, partition, uefi

How i can get the uuid in uefi of a partition which i have the device_handle of?
 For example i'm iterating through the partitions in uefi and i want to get the uuid of the partition. (This is a gpt disk.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "GPT Partition Entry" has 2 GUIDs

> **PartitionTypeGUID** Unique ID that defines the purpose and type of this
>   Partition. A value of zero defines that this partition entry is not
>   being used.
>
> **UniquePartitionGUID** GUID that is unique for every partition entry.
>   Every partition ever created will have a unique GUID. This GUID must
>   be assigned when the GPT Partition Entry is created. The GPT Partition
>   Entry is created whenever the NumberOfPartitionEntr ies in the GPT
>   Header is increased to include a larger range of addresses.

I consider you are looking for the **UniquePartitionGUID**

If you have the partition associated device_handle then you can get the corresponding DevicePath i.e using gnu-efi

```
DevicePath=DevicePathFromHandle(partition_handle);
```

next you parse the DevicePath looking for a node as follow

```
-Generic Device Path Header- where

Type = Media Device Path (0x04)
Sub type = Hard Drive (0x01)
... 
Partition Signature = partition GUID  <<<<<<<<
Partition Format = GPT (0x02)
```

within this structure you'll find your needed GUID

Reference UEFI spec 2.5 (chapter 9)

Answer (score 0):

In the GPT header at offset 56 is a 16-byte DiskGUID that can be used to uniquely identify the disk. (Efi specs 5.3.2).